# REGEXP only numbers withouth parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

I want RegExp: 
**I need Numbers without Parenthesis.**

JAVA PROGRAMMING **20** (2016) <- **I need get number 20**

JAVA PROGRAMMING **30** (2016) <- **I need get number 30**


For parenthesis is:

```
(\(.*)\)
```

For Numbers

```
\d
```

**I need it for PHP Language. Thank you !**


I was Trying here: http://regexr.com/

Comment: Show your `regexr` attempts.

Comment: Please rewrite this question so it clearly states what you're trying to do, what you've tried so far, and what that results in.  This reads like a random group of copy-pasted things vaguely related to regular expressions

Comment: Done. sorry dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need Numbers without Parenthesis.

Use `preg_match_all` function with specific regex pattern:

```
$str = 'JAVA PROGRAMMING 20 (2016) JAVA PROGRAMMING 30 (2016)';
preg_match_all("/(?!\()\b\d+\b(?!\))/", $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 30
)
```